# Using redis with Gitlab CI

Tags: redis, continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am currently using serverless framework and setting up gitlab ci using shared runner.

Following is my gitlab-ci.yml:

```
image: node:latest

services:
  - redis

cache:
  paths:
    - node_modules/
    - java/

stages:
  - build
  - test
  - review
  - staging
  - production

build:
  stage: build
  script:
      - npm install
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - node_modules/

install:java:
  stage: build
  script:
      - apt-get update
      - apt-get install -y default-jre default-jdk openjdk-7-jre openjdk-7-jdk
      - apt-get update
      - sls dynamodb install
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - java/

connect:
  image: redis
  script:
  - redis-cli -h redis PING

unit test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - sls dynamodb start
    - babel-node ./aws/createDB.js
    - npm run unit
  dependencies:
    - build
    - install:java
```

unit test job requires redis and is not able to connect. Following error gets thrown, when unit test job starts:

> Error while creating redis client: Error: Redis connection to
>   127.0.0.1:6379 failed - connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379

Can someone point out what's wrong with current config file, thanks!

Comment: Answer below is true, but if you already have taken it into accout, it is possible that you are not setting correctly your credentials to redis (example : you are passing a configuration object and the host key is mislocated). If no creds are found, most libraries default to 127.0.0.1:6379 which also explains your error

Answer (score 24):

The host address of the redis service is `redis` not `127.0.0.1` or `localhost`.

So make sure you set the host for the redis service to `redis` in all of your scripts and configuration files.

Comment: + the doc about accessing a service: https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html#accessing-the-services

Answer (score 5):

Just to make people's life easier, I list an example `.gitlab-ci.yml` to configure Redis in Gitlab CI.

```
services:
  - redis:latest

stages:
  - test

test:
 script:
   - echo "hello world!"
 stage: test
 variables:
    REDIS_PORT: 6379
    REDIS_HOST: redis
    REDIS_URL: redis://redis:6379
```